# the switch statement is valid for comparing BYTE/Char//Short/Int variables..Am i wrong?

Tags: java

i saw this code somewhere

```
 switch(greet){
  case HELLO:
      System.out.println("Formal Greeting");
      break;
  case HI:
      System.out.println("Friendly Greeting");
      break;
  case YO:
      System.out.println("Informal Greeting");
      break;
  default:
      System.out.println("Person did not greet");
 }
```

It did not mention the type of datatype of the **greet** variable against which the cases are being checked.. but it's east to figure out that it's **neither a  byte,nor is it a Short or Int** So logically the last permissible data type left for the switch block to accept as a variable is the **char** data type but i believe that char only takes single values like 'c' or '3' ..so how do such big values like **hello** get evaluated? what is the possible explanation?

Comment: `greet`, `hello`, `hi`, and `yo` are all **variables,** not **values**. There is no way to know what type `greet` is without seeing more code.

Comment: I guess,you will do more favour to us by giving little more snippet of your code.What are greet,hello,hi ,yo..?These need to be constant expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that this is an Enum, and hello is an enum constant declared on the Enum.
So basically what we have here is:

```
public enum greet {
     hello,
     hi,
     yo;
}
```

[Enum docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: what's an enum? could you elaborate?

Comment: An enum is a java type with constant fields, I updated my post with the documentation.

Comment: @OscarMk, this is quite the assumption! @nav, this is a strong possibility, but this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @Little bunny foo foo, yeah I know there is really no way to tell from the code, but I guess this could be the case.

Comment: @OscarMk, I disagree. Standard naming convention dictates that `enums` are capitalized, although it's entirely possible that the developer deviated from this standard.

Comment: @little bunny foo foo, yes I am aware that is the standard, but as we know unfortunately not everyone follows standards.

Comment: @OscarMk, yeah...it's too bad :/

Comment: ok!! thanks OscarMk .. i buy this explanation :)   and ya @little bunny foo foo - they were capitalized.. i typed it as lower case by mistake :-)   my bad :(

Answer (score 1):

From what you've shown, any permissible data type is possible.

Comment: but the only permissible data types are int , short, char and byte.. and i believe "hello" or "yo" or "hi" do not belong to neither of these :(

Comment: @nav, those are _variables_, not _values_, as @Matt Ball stated.

Comment: bunny foo foo - they were capitalized.. i typed it as lower case by mistake ! my bad :(

Comment: `static` constants are also known to be capitalized...I still think you're assuming way too much. :)

Comment: any permissible data type is possible as far as they are constant